# jqGrid. Checkbox SelectAll

Tags: checkbox, jqgrid

How to programmatically in jqgrid to set the value (checked/not) of the SelectAll checkbox (see picture https://drive.google.com/open?id=1fEb1qaskPyz88uuqSCYscCiaCFdjktis).

How to know the status of the SelectAll checkbox without previous saving to a variable the result onSelectAll

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to help you better, would be helpful if you could let us know what you have tried so far to solve your problem. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The id of the selectAll checkbox is combination of cb_ plus the id of the grid.

By example if the grid has id = jqGrid, then the id of the selectAll checkbox is **cb_jqGrid**

To change the status just trigger a click

```
var $selectall = $("#cb_jqGrid");
$selectall.click()
```

to get the state use jQuery .is

```
if( $selectall.is(":checked") ) {
    alert("Is checked");
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help! Everything works fine!